# How to select appropriate sin() terms to fit a time series using R

Tags: r, regression

I want to fit a time series with `sin()` function because it has a form of some periods (crests and troughs). However, for now I only guessed it, e.g., 1 month, two months, ..., 1 year, 2 year. Is there some function in R to estimate the multiple periods in a data series?

Below is an example which I want to fit it using the combination of `sin()` functions. The expression in `lm()` is a try after several guesses (red line in the Figure below). How can I find the `sin()` terms with appropriate periods?

```
t <- 1:365
y <- c(-1,-1.3,-1.6,-1.8,-2.1,-2.3,-2.5,-2.7,-2.9,-3,-2,-1.1,-0.3,0.5,1.1,1.6,2.1,2.5,2.8,3.1,3.4,3.7,4.2,4.6,5,5.3,5.7,5.9,6.2,5.8,5.4,5,4.6,4.2,3.9,3.6,3.4,3.1,2.9,2.8,2.6,2.5,2.3,1.9,1.5,1.1,0.8,0.5,0.2,0,-0.1,-0.3,-0.4,-0.5,-0.5,-0.6,-0.7,-0.8,-0.9,-0.8,-0.6,-0.3,-0.1,0.1,0.4,0.6,0.9,1.1,1.3,1.5,1.7,2.1,2.4,2.7,3,3.3,3.5,3.8,4.3,4.7,5.1,5.5,5.9,6.2,6.4,6.6,6.7,6.8,6.8,6.9,7,6.9,6.8,6.7,
       6.5,6.4,6.4,6.3,6.2,6,5.9,5.7,5.6,5.5,5.4,5.4,5.1,4.9,4.8,4.6,4.5,4.4,4.3,3.9,3.6,3.3,3,2.8,2.6,2.4,2.6,2.5,2.4,2.3,2.3,2.2,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.4,2.5,2.5,2.6,2.6,2.4,2.1,1.9,1.8,1.6,1.4,1.3,1,0.7,0.5,0.2,0,-0.2,-0.4,-0.2,-0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0,0,-0.1,-0.1,-0.2,-0.2,-0.3,-0.3,-0.4,-0.5,-0.5,-0.6,-0.7,-0.7,-0.8,-0.8,-0.8,-0.9,-0.9,-0.9,-1.3,-1.6,-1.9,-2.1,-2.3,-2.6,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,
       -2.9,-3,-3,-3,-2.8,-2.7,-2.5,-2.4,-2.3,-2.2,-2.1,-2,-2,-1.9,-1.9,-1.8,-1.8,-1.8,-1.9,-1.9,-2,-2.1,-2.2,-2.2,-2.3,-2.4,-2.5,-2.6,-2.7,-2.8,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.8,-2.8,-2.7,-2.7,-2.6,-2.6,-2.8,-3,-3.1,-3.3,-3.4,-3.5,-3.6,-3.5,-3.4,-3.3,-3.3,-3.2,-3,-2.9,-2.8,-2.8,-2.7,-2.6,-2.6,-2.6,-2.5,-2.6,-2.7,-2.8,-2.8,-2.9,-3,-3,-3,-3,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.8,
       -2.7,-2.6,-2.5,-2.4,-2.3,-2.3,-2.1,-1.9,-1.8,-1.7,-1.5,-1.4,-1.3,-1.5,-1.7,-1.8,-1.9,-2,-2.1,-2.2,-2.4,-2.5,-2.6,-2.7,-2.8,-2.8,-2.9,-3.1,-3.2,-3.3,-3.4,-3.5,-3.5,-3.6,-3.6,-3.5,-3.4,-3.3,-3.2,-3.1,-3,-2.7,-2.3,-2,-1.8,-1.5,-1.3,-1.1,-0.9,-0.7,-0.6,-0.5,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,-0.3,-0.5,-0.6,-0.7,-0.8,-0.9,-1,-1.1,-1.1,-1.2,-1.2,-1.2,-1.2,-1.2,-0.8,-0.4,-0.1,0.2,0.5,0.8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.6,0.3,0,-0.2,-0.5,-0.7,-0.8)

dt <- data.frame(t = t, y = y)
plot(x = dt$t, y = dt$y)

lm <- lm(y ~ sin(2*3.1416/365*t)+cos(2*3.1416/365*t)+
           sin(2*2*3.1416/365*t)+cos(2*2*3.1416/365*t)+
           sin(2*4*3.1416/365*t)+cos(2*4*3.1416/365*t)+
           sin(2*5*3.1416/365*t)+cos(2*5*3.1416/365*t)+
           sin(2*6*3.1416/365*t)+cos(2*6*3.1416/365*t)+
           sin(2*0.5*3.1416/365*t)+cos(2*0.5*3.1416/365*t),
         data = dt)

summary(lm)$adj.r.squared
plot(dt$y); lines(predict(lm), type = "l", col = "red")
```

[image: Fig1]

Comment: In [catastrophic-failure's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41465250/8245406) replace `Mod` by `Re` as in [SleuthEye's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49503143/8245406). Then call `nff(y, 20, col = "red")`.

Comment: If you are just looking to fit a parametric model then try this autoregressive model: `a <- ar(dt$y);
plot(dt, pch = 20, cex = 0.8);
fit <- dt$y - a$resid;
lines(fit, col = "red")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my comment to the question,

> In [catastrophic-failure's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41465250/8245406) replace Mod by Re as in [SleuthEye's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49503143/8245406). Then call `nff(y, 20, col = "red")`.

I realized that there is another correction to function `nff` to be made:

- substitute `length(x)` or `xlen` for the [magical number 73](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435777/perform-fourier-analysis-to-a-time-series-in-r#comment104883864_41465250).

Here is the function corrected.

```r
nff = function(x = NULL, n = NULL, up = 10L, plot = TRUE, add = FALSE, main = NULL, ...){
  #The direct transformation
  #The first frequency is DC, the rest are duplicated
  dff = fft(x)
  #The time
  xlen <- length(x)
  t = seq_along(x)
  #Upsampled time
  nt = seq(from = 1L, to = xlen + 1L - 1/up, by = 1/up)
  #New spectrum
  ndff = array(data = 0, dim = c(length(nt), 1L))
  ndff[1] = dff[1] #Always, it's the DC component
  if(n != 0){
    ndff[2:(n+1)] <- dff[2:(n+1)] #The positive frequencies always come first
    #The negative ones are trickier
    ndff[(length(ndff) - n + 1):length(ndff)] <- dff[(xlen - n + 1L):xlen]
  }
  #The inverses
  indff = fft(ndff/xlen, inverse = TRUE)
  idff = fft(dff/xlen, inverse = TRUE)
  if(plot){
    if(!add){
      plot(x = t, y = x, pch = 16L, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Measurement",
           main = ifelse(is.null(main), paste(n, "harmonics"), main))
      lines(y = Re(idff), x = t, col = adjustcolor(1L, alpha = 0.5))
    }
    lines(y = Re(indff), x = nt, ...)
  }
  ret = data.frame(time = nt, y = Mod(indff))
  return(ret)
}

y <- c(-1,-1.3,-1.6,-1.8,-2.1,-2.3,-2.5,-2.7,-2.9,-3,-2,-1.1,-0.3,0.5,1.1,1.6,2.1,2.5,2.8,3.1,3.4,3.7,4.2,4.6,5,5.3,5.7,5.9,6.2,5.8,5.4,5,4.6,4.2,3.9,3.6,3.4,3.1,2.9,2.8,2.6,2.5,2.3,1.9,1.5,1.1,0.8,0.5,0.2,0,-0.1,-0.3,-0.4,-0.5,-0.5,-0.6,-0.7,-0.8,-0.9,-0.8,-0.6,-0.3,-0.1,0.1,0.4,0.6,0.9,1.1,1.3,1.5,1.7,2.1,2.4,2.7,3,3.3,3.5,3.8,4.3,4.7,5.1,5.5,5.9,6.2,6.4,6.6,6.7,6.8,6.8,6.9,7,6.9,6.8,6.7,
       6.5,6.4,6.4,6.3,6.2,6,5.9,5.7,5.6,5.5,5.4,5.4,5.1,4.9,4.8,4.6,4.5,4.4,4.3,3.9,3.6,3.3,3,2.8,2.6,2.4,2.6,2.5,2.4,2.3,2.3,2.2,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.4,2.5,2.5,2.6,2.6,2.4,2.1,1.9,1.8,1.6,1.4,1.3,1,0.7,0.5,0.2,0,-0.2,-0.4,-0.2,-0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0,0,-0.1,-0.1,-0.2,-0.2,-0.3,-0.3,-0.4,-0.5,-0.5,-0.6,-0.7,-0.7,-0.8,-0.8,-0.8,-0.9,-0.9,-0.9,-1.3,-1.6,-1.9,-2.1,-2.3,-2.6,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,
       -2.9,-3,-3,-3,-2.8,-2.7,-2.5,-2.4,-2.3,-2.2,-2.1,-2,-2,-1.9,-1.9,-1.8,-1.8,-1.8,-1.9,-1.9,-2,-2.1,-2.2,-2.2,-2.3,-2.4,-2.5,-2.6,-2.7,-2.8,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.8,-2.8,-2.7,-2.7,-2.6,-2.6,-2.8,-3,-3.1,-3.3,-3.4,-3.5,-3.6,-3.5,-3.4,-3.3,-3.3,-3.2,-3,-2.9,-2.8,-2.8,-2.7,-2.6,-2.6,-2.6,-2.5,-2.6,-2.7,-2.8,-2.8,-2.9,-3,-3,-3,-3,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.9,-2.8,
       -2.7,-2.6,-2.5,-2.4,-2.3,-2.3,-2.1,-1.9,-1.8,-1.7,-1.5,-1.4,-1.3,-1.5,-1.7,-1.8,-1.9,-2,-2.1,-2.2,-2.4,-2.5,-2.6,-2.7,-2.8,-2.8,-2.9,-3.1,-3.2,-3.3,-3.4,-3.5,-3.5,-3.6,-3.6,-3.5,-3.4,-3.3,-3.2,-3.1,-3,-2.7,-2.3,-2,-1.8,-1.5,-1.3,-1.1,-0.9,-0.7,-0.6,-0.5,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,-0.3,-0.5,-0.6,-0.7,-0.8,-0.9,-1,-1.1,-1.1,-1.2,-1.2,-1.2,-1.2,-1.2,-0.8,-0.4,-0.1,0.2,0.5,0.8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.6,0.3,0,-0.2,-0.5,-0.7,-0.8)

res <- nff(y, 20, col = "red")
```

[image]

```r
str(res)
#> 'data.frame':    3650 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ time: num  1 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 ...
#>  $ y   : num  1.27 1.31 1.34 1.37 1.4 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Technically correct, but 20 harmonics might be overfitting, depending on the application ...

Comment: @BenBolker It's almost a Lagrange polynomial... But there was a good answer already.

Answer (score 3):

Package `forecast` has the `fourier` function (see [here](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/forecast/html/fourier.html)), which allows you to model fourier series terms based on time series objects.

For example:

```
library(forecast)
dt$y <- ts(dt$y, frequency = 365)

lm<- lm(y ~ fourier(y, K=6), dt)
plot(dt$t, dt$y); lines(predict(lm), type = "l", col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment...

Comment: I added a code example. The question was if it was a function in R that allow estimate multiple periods and by the example it seems fourier terms was appropiate.

Comment: Done. However i must add that the second question "finding appropiate periods" is perhaps beyond the scope of this forum and the answer is more about the firs question, about a function that do modelling of periods.

Answer (score 1):

The functions `sinusoid` and `mvrm` from package `BNSP` allow one to specify the number of harmonics and if that number is too high, the algorithm can remove some of the unnecessary terms and avoid overfitting.

```
# Specify the model
model <- y ~ sinusoid(t, harmonics = 20, amplitude = 1, period = 365) 
# Fit the model
m1 <- mvrm(formula = model, data = dt, sweeps = 5000, burn = 3000, thin = 2, seed = 1, StorageDir = getwd())
# ggplot
plotOptionsM <- list(geom_point(data = dt, aes(x = t, y = y)))
plot(x = m1, term = 1, plotOptions = plotOptionsM, intercept = TRUE, quantiles = c(0.005, 0.995), grid = 100)
```

In this particular example, among the 20 harmonics, the 19 appear to be important.

[image]