# How to frequency filter a time series in R

Tags: r, filter, time-series, fft

I'd like to know how to apply frequency filters to a time series in R and get the result back in the time domain (e.g. fourier transform -> get rid of certain frequencies -> inverse fourier transform) or a similar approach (there does not seem to be a suitable inverse function to `fft`). From what I have seen people recommend the `signal` package, but I don't seem to be able to get sensible results with this package. So to put an example. Let's say I have a simple monthy time series:

```r
plot(log(AirPassengers))
```

[image]

Let's say I want to extract these seasonal fluctuations here using a band-pass filter (i.e. get rid of the trend and the small higher frequency movements). If someone could produce an R code do do this by fourier methods, preferably using a package function, and explain it that would be of great help to get me started.

Comment: does it *have to be* Fourier analysis? You could also look at autocorrelation ... check `?decompose` and `?acf`

Comment: also, seems very related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435777/perform-fourier-analysis-to-a-time-series-in-r/41465250

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually not interested in seasonality as such, this was just an example to encourage practical examples. So yes I want to do proper signal processing on the series. Thanks for the link, it appears this somehow works, but it's a lot of hand coding and I also don't really understand the code (e.g. why is he calculating two different inverses, why is he dividing by 73?). A solution using a package function would be great.

Comment: there's the wild and wooly world of `tsmp`, `tsmp::analyze(log(AirPassengers))`, all fft based.

Comment: I've found something that comes pretty close to what I want: `plot(mFilter::trfilter(log(AirPassengers), 2, 6, drift=TRUE))` based on trigonometric regression instead of fourier transform. Fourier transform would of course be more exact, but if there is nothing else I'm happy with this.